# CSS Modules multiple class selectors

Tags: css, reactjs, css-modules, react-css-modules

I am using CSS Modules and `react-css-modules`. I have a `.app-link` class.

```
<NavLink to="/" styleName="app-link">
SBP Investments
</NavLink>
```

In my CSS file

```
.app-link {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.app-link.active {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

Now I want to be able to target `.app-link.active` how do I do that?

Comment: what do you mean by 'to target'?

Comment: @Dan, I am able to style .App-link. but how do I style it when it is in active state?

Comment: `.app-link.active` is a proper selector to an element with both `.applink` and `.active` classes. Are you sure that your mechanism for toggling `.active` class works ?